# Make a Wi-Fi emitting device visible on another network

Tags: networking, wifi, iptables-redirect, iot

I have a raspberry pi connected by wifi to a sensor (network A) that emits its own Wi-Fi signal and that is controlled from an Android application on a device connected to the Wi-Fi that emits the sensor and by cable to a wifi repeater (network B). I need to know if it is possible to redirect all traffic from network A to network B so that any device connected to network B has access to the sensor's functions in the same way as if it were connected to the sensor's Wi-Fi directly.